# How to use RotateAround to achieve different speed zones by angle

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation

I'm trying to rotate the camera around certain object.
With the addition that **on some specific part of the rotation, and during certain angle, the movement should be slow**.

Illustrated representation below, green zone is the zone of slow motion, red one is the normal speed applied:

[image]

To achieve this, I'm using the `Transform.RotateAround(Vector3 point, Vector3 axis, float angle)` method

So, guessing that the slow speed is the half of the original speed, and the angleOfSlowMotionZone is 90º like the picture, I do the follow:

- Calculate the time that it takes the camera to arrive to the slow zone (green), which will be:

  `timeToArriveToSlowZone = (270 - (angleOfSlowMotionZone / 2)) / speed;`
- Calculate the time necessary to end the slow zone:

  `timeToEndSlowZone = angleOfSlowMotionZone / slowSpeed;`
- Finally calculate the time to do the whole TurnAround:

  `timeToFullTurn = timeToArriveToSlowZone + timeToEndSlowZone;`

Then I call a Coroutine to do the movement like:

```
IEnumerator Rotation()
{
    second = 0;
    while(true)
    {
        second += Time.deltaTime;
        if(second >= timeToFullTurn)            
            second = 0;                
        newSpeed = (second <= timeToArriveToSlowZone || second >= timeToArriveToSlowZone + timeToEndSlowZone) ? speed : slowSpeed;            
        transform.RotateAround(targetGO.transform.position, Vector3.up, newSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        yield return null;
    }
}
```

My problem is that in each turn, the moment to slow down the movement, is a little different. How can I fix that to be **EXACTLY** as the angle suggested?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has issues handling when it goes over 360, it gets set exactly at 0 instead of an appropriate amount greater than 0. Also, you assume the rotation speed should be the same for the entire frame based on the section the frame begins with, instead of being dependent on how early or late into the frame the section changes.

I would use a nested while loop for this, which would also account for if the speed is fast enough or the deltaTime is large enough to change sections multiple times in the same frame. Explanation in comments:

```
IEnumerator Rotation(float startAngle)
{
    // parameters - could be fields
    float baseMoveSpeed = 90f;
    float slowMoveSpeed = 45f;
    float slowMoveAngle = 90f;

    float angleAtStartOfFrame = startAngle;

    while(true)
    {
        float timeLeft = Time.deltaTime;
        float newAngle = angleAtStartOfFrame;

        // Travel through sections until time this frame is accounted for
        while (timeLeft > 0)
        {
            float speed;
            float curRegionRemaining;

            // assume slow move region is from newAngle=0 to newAngle=slowMoveAngle
            if (newAngle < slowMoveAngle)
            {
                speed = slowMoveSpeed;
                curRegionRemaining = slowMoveAngle - newAngle;
            } 
            else
            {
                speed = baseMoveSpeed;
                curRegionRemaining = 360f - newAngle;
            }

            // travel to end of current region or as much as you can 
            // travel with remaining time
            float angleTraveledThisSection = Mathf.Min(timeLeft * speed,
                    curRegionRemaining);

            // how much time did that use?
            float timeUsedThisSection = angleTraveledThisSection / speed;

            // how much time is left to travel this frame?
            timeLeft -= timeUsedThisSection;

            // sum up how much travel has done
            newAngle = Mathf.Repeat(newAngle + angleTraveledThisSection, 360f);
        }

        transform.RotateAround(targetGO.transform.position, Vector3.up, 
                newAngle - angleAtStartOfFrame);

        angleAtStartOfFrame = newAngle;
        yield return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow Ruzihm, you allways saves my day! It certainly works (There is only one typo-mistake that I will edit right now), but everything works perfect. My problem is that I don't really get it WHY this approach. Correct me if I'm incorrect, you are trying to say that because my >= check won't be exact, I'm carrying that error every turn, right? My problem is that I don't understand how your code solve it.

Comment: That part is you're doing `second += Time.deltaTime;
        if(second >= timeToFullTurn)            
            second = 0;  `. Suppose `deltaTime` is `0.02` and `second` before this code is run is `359.9999`. After, `second` **should** be closer to `0.02` than `0`. But your code makes it `0`, ignoring how close it was already to `360`. I'm also unsure why you used `timeToArriveToSlowZone = (270 - (angleOfSlowMotionZone / 2)) / speed;` instead of `timeToArriveToSlowZone = (360 - angleOfSlowMotionZone) / speed;` but I decided to avoid that math.

Comment: Okey, so it is this carrying problem. Will be a similar approach to do on my original code: `if (second >= timeToFullTurn) second = timeToFullTurn - second;` ? Or I'm missing something?

Comment: No, that would go the wrong direction, giving you something more like `359.8`. You could instead do `second = second + Time.deltaTime; if (second >= timeToFullturn) second = second - timeToFullTurn;` or `second += Time.deltaTime; if (second >= timeToFullturn) second -= timeToFullTurn;` or most simply, `second = Mathf.Repeat(second + Time.deltaTime, timeToFullTurn);`, which is similar to what I did. I used `Repeat` over angles instead of time but the concept is similar.

Comment: Oh my brain, of course, I swapped the values, thanks, I'm learning so much from your answers! And I've calculated weird like this cause I was thinking that if the angleOfSlowMotion starts at, for example, 225º, and his arc is 90º, 360-90 != 225.